# Can soil carry enough current to electrocute you?

Tags: grounding, safety

I'm a bit worried about using electricity outside, but I see that pretty much everyone has some type of outdoor lighting, so I might just be paranoid. Anyway, I was wondering how dangerous outdoor cables actually are, especially in a worst case scenario type of thing.

Say a live damaged cable with 230V touches wet soil. Would that be dangerous for people nearby? Would that wire just be technically grounded?
Is there any way to ballpark any figures about how much voltage/current could be present at a certain distance from the wire?

Comment: I think key to safe use of mains electricity (especially in moist, damp environments) is the use of a residual-current circuit breaker (which also goes by the name of a ground fault circuit interrupter). Any damaged live cable is inherently dangerous, but there are measures to reduce that danger.

Comment: 10mA can stop your heart.  So yes, soil can carry enough current to kill you.   You don't need to explode in a ball of lightning to die.   Electricity also kills people indirectly -- i.e. you touch a bare wire while you're on a ladder, lose control of your muscles, and then fall to your death.

Comment: In addition to the advice below, make sure you only use equipment (especially plugs, sockets or connection boxes, and obviously the devices you want to power) which are designed for outdoor use. You don’t want to just use an indoor extension cord or lamp outside for instance.

Comment: Keep in mind, as you read the answers ,  downed power lines are completely different than faults of exterior wiring. Downed power lines present a significant safety hazard to anyone around them ,.

Answer (score 5):

These days, most folk install ground fault current protection devices and, upon detection of a current flowing into ground (rather than it returning through the normal cable conduction path), the device trips and makes the installation safe.

Think about fish ponds with lots of expensive koi carp and AC powered pump motors. It would be borderline legally negligent of me not to have these types of devices fitted. Even more so if humans can be affected.

> *Anyway, I was wondering how dangerous outdoor cables actually are,
> especially in a worst case scenario type of thing.*

In worst case scenarios people will die. Avoid reaching that scenario with an RCD (residual current device) or a GFCI (ground fault current interrupter).

> *Say a live damaged cable with 230V touches wet soil. Would that be
> dangerous for people nearby?*

Barefoot and touching something else that is earthed yes; but, for less than a few tens of milliseconds providing you have an RCD or GFCI fitted it won't be lethal. If you don't have one fitted it's dangerous because nothing will trip except the fuse and, fuses are rated in amps or tens of amps and probably nobody will survive that sort of current waiting a few seconds for the fuse to trip. An RCD or GFCI should usually trip within tens of milliseconds on ground currents in excess of 30 mA.

> *Is there any way to ballpark any figures about how much
> voltage/current could be present at a certain distance from the wire?*

Try looking up what a nearby lightning strike will produce in terms of voltage per metre then, scale it down if you really want to know what you might get with 10 amps flowing through earth. It's not as much as you think but, it still can be dangerous depending how uninsulated a person is laying down on a damp grassy surface wearing nothing but swimwear.

How an RCD works: -

[image]

Image from [RCDs and the 18th Edition (wiring regulations UK)](https://www.voltimum.co.uk/articles/rcds-and-18th-edition).

How a GCFI works (same story as an RCD): -

[image]

Image from [GFCI defined](https://www.guardiangfci.com/knowledge/gfci-defined).

Take note that an earth wire is not needed for an RCD (or GCFI) to operate successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Just to clarify, *[to get electrocuted](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-spanish/electrocute)* means to die of electric shock. So we can correctly say you got electrocuted if you died. If you didn't die, then you just received an electric shock, not an electrocution.

---

> Can soil carry enough current to electrocute you?

In terms of you receiving an electric shock or even worse electrocuting, it's not relevant.

The reason is because it's not necessarily dangerous to touch a wire carrying current. Whether or not it's dangerous depends on other factors. If you *1)* touch with one or both hands wires of a same phase (be it phase *a*, *b* or *c*); and *2)* you're not touching anything else, not even Earth ground/the soil; and *3)* the wire you touch isn't at hundreds of thousands of RMS volts, then you shouldn't receive an electric shock. This explains why birds standing on distribution lines don't die.

As a first example, why do pigeons standing on distribution lines don't die, even though the wires are carrying huge amounts of current, and there are thousands of RMS volts between the wires? Because the pigeons are satisfying the three conditions I mentioned in the previous paragraph. That is, because they're touching one wire and only one wire, nothing else; and the wires have about 13.8 kV RMS line-to-line. They do not simultaneously touch two conductors at different electric potential (that is, their entire body is practically at the same potential, so there is no potential *difference* between the two contact points/legs, and therefore there is no voltage applied to their body). (Remember that voltage is electric potential difference.)

On the other hand, bats sometimes die because they do touch two conductors at different potentials simultaneously with their wings (that is, there is a potential differential between the two contact points, and therefore there is a voltage applied to their body).

This is shown next.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: own.*

The two legs of the pigeon form, together with the segment of the transmission/distribution line between the two legs of the pigeon, a current divider. Since the electrical resistance/impedance of the pigeon is much greater than the impedance of the line segment between the two legs of the pigeon (remember that a real wire has impedance), the current through the pigeon will be very low. On the other hand, the bat is applied line voltage across its wings and body (for example 13.8 kV RMS), which divided by the bat's electrical resistance will result in a lethal current. This is shown next.

[image]

*Figure 2. Image source: own.*

Note: on very high voltage lines (about over 100 kilovolts RMS), an electric arc can form even if you try to touch just one wire. For this reason, the engineers in charge of maintaining these lines (or linemen) first touch them with a special "stick", so that the arc does not touch them first. **[Example video](https://youtu.be/DPNK7bc2qvM?t=120)** (from time 2:00).

So, as you can see, **whether a wire carrying current is dangerous or not is irrelevant. What matters is if the wire has a voltage with respect to Earth ground**. A wire is said to be *live/hot/active* if it has voltage w.r.t. earth, not if it carries current. **It doesn't matter whether the wires are carrying no current or are carrying 10 A RMS; what matters is the current *through you* and the voltage *across you*, not the current *through the wires***.

---

To further prove the previous statement, as a second example, consider an electric fence. First I briefly clarify how an electric fence works. A device provides a voltage between its two terminals. One terminal is connected to the wires of the electric fence, and the other terminal is connected to a rod that is driven into the Earth ground. Under normal conditions, there is no conductor/body *simultaneously* touching some fence wire and Earth ground, so there is an open circuit and no current is flowing. But if a thief/ animal/person touches a wire, and if his feet/legs are touching the ground, then his body will complete the circuit and they will receive an electric shock. The following image clarifies it:

[image]

*Figure 3. Image source: unknown, I found it many months ago.*

In **[this video](https://youtu.be/N8fwtkC5UJU)** a dog urinates on an electric fence. The urine, along with the dog's body and legs, act as a bridge to connect the wires of the electric fence to the ground, thus completing the circuit. The dog receives a shock.

In **[this video](https://youtu.be/4SIT0aU_FRw)**, several kids form a human chain, and one of them touches a wire from an electric fence. But all of them are isolated from earth, so there is no complete circuit, and they do not get a shock. Later in the video, one of the kids stands on the ground, completing the circuit between the fence and the ground through the human chain, causing everyone to receive a shock.

---

Third example. The hot wire (and sometimes also the neutral wire) of an outlet is dangerous to touch whether there is a load connected (carrying current) or not (not carrying current), because at any case you'll apply 120 V RMS between your hands and feet, since the circuit is grounded at the transformer and at the main panel and so you complete the circuit between hot and ground. This is shown in the two following figures, assuming ideal wires for simplicity.

[image]

*Figure 4. With load. There was current flowing before you touched the wire, and also after you touched it. There are 120 V RMS across you after you touch the wire. It's dangerous. Image source: own.*

[image]

*Figure 5. Without load. There was no current flowing before you touched the wire, only after you touched it. There are 120 V RMS across you after you touch the wire. It's still dangerous. Image source: own.*

What kills you is if *you* complete a circuit and put 120 V or 240 V (in the US) *across you*, either by touching a live wire and ground, or two live wires of different phase. And if you don't have a GFCI/RCD as the breaker for the circuit, the situation is even more dangerous since once you complete the circuit, the current won't be high enough to trip the breaker as an overload condition (15 or 20 A), let alone a short-circuit condition (thousands of amps), nor will there be a mechanism that detects there's a leakage of current and trips the breaker (i.e. the GFCI/RCD), but the current will be high enough (over hundreds of milliamperes) to kill you.

---

> Say a live damaged cable with 230V touches wet soil. Would that be
> dangerous for people nearby?

If a live wire touches the earth ground, a circuited is closed consisting of the ground rods, the installation wires, and the soil; this condition is known as a *ground fault*. (If you don’t know about this, I suggest you to please watch **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJeRabV5hNU)** and **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-W42tk-fWc&t=44s)** [for the US] many times until you understand them and remember what's explained, since the explanation and illustrations are very good; also, study the diagram explained in **[this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/1708/118466)** [for the US.])

If the soil resistance between where the ground rod is and where the live wire touches the soil/ground is low, a high current will flow and that will be dangerous since it could cause a fire. If the soil resistance is high, the circuit breaker won't trip due to an overload (20-25 A RMS), let alone due to a short-circuit (thousands of amperes); but I think this is not dangerous as in delivering electric shocks to anyone standing on ground.

When the hot/live wire touches ground, there’s now a 2D electric potential as a function of the radial distance from where the live/hot wire touched Earth ground to any other point on the Earth ground (such as each of your feet); this is usually called *Earth surface voltage gradient* (which should actually be called *Earth surface potential* because that’s what it is); it is usually illustrated in diagrams as equipotential curves. Because the soil resistivity is significantly high, the potential falls significantly per unit distance. That is, the potential difference (or voltage) between two nearby points (such as your feet), known as *step potential* (which should actually be called *step voltage* because it’s a potential difference), is high. So, between your feet there will be a high voltage, causing a high current to flow through you. To more safely exit from that situation, make small hops (jumps with one leg), to not complete the circuit, or small jumps with both legs touching each other, to make the step voltage as low as possible. For more info, read [Earth/ground potential rise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_potential_rise).

This is why when a hot/live wire of a power line falls to ground, you should stay away from it. It’s also why when a lightning strikes the ground, you can receive an electric shock even if the lightning didn’t strike you directly, but you’re close to the striking point.

[image]

*Figure 6. Image source: [gbe2b](https://gbe2b.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/how-to-survive-a-fiery-wreck/step-potential/).*

[image]

*Figure 7. Image source: [Tiva Rodriguez](https://www.slideserve.com/tiva/110-kv).*

[image]

*Figure 8. Image source: [Mick1985](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF09Z.jpg).*

There are or were power systems that used dirt/soil/ground/earth as a conductor, called **[single-wire earth-return systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_earth_return)**.

---

> Would that wire just be technically grounded?

Well, it is kind of grounded as in touching Earth ground/soil, but it still has 120 V RMS (in the US, or 230 V RMS where you live) with respect to Earth ground, so it is still dangerous to touch it.

---

> Is there any way to ballpark any figures about how much
> voltage/current could be present at a certain distance from the wire?

Maybe you could estimate the length of the wires, the distance between the ground rod and where the live wire touched the soil, and the soil resistivity, then you could calculate the voltage by using basic laws (Kirchhoff's, Ohm's). But to be honest I'm not sure how accurate this would be. Though since you're asking for an approximation, this should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very well put together. As for estimating voltage, if we consider wet soil resistivity at about 20 ohm m, that would mean that 1m away from the live wire, the voltage over a resistor of 1k ohm for the sake of roundness, would be almost mains level. Which sounds pretty bad and dangerous, but I don't know if this is how it should be calculated.